# Autostart node.js app with startup options

Tags: node.js, windows, autostart

I would like to autostart my node.js application and server with every boot of the Windows Server 2016 OS.

I already found "node-windows" and "qckwinsvc" as possible solutions, but I do not understand how I can start my application with the startup options I saved in the package.json provided below (e.g. host, prod, ip, max-old-space-size, etc.)

Furthermore, I would like to know if these services also restart the node application in case it crashed due to a programmatical error (e.g. javascript heap out of memory)

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href ./",
    "build-dev": "ng build --base-href ./",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "app": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --prod --open",
    "app-dev": "ng serve --host=localhost --open",
    "server": "export NODE_ENV=production && export IP=172.28.0.19 && node --max-old-space-size=4096 server/server.ts",
    "server-dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && export IP=localhost && node server/server.ts",
    "static": "http-server ./dist/lead -p 8080 -a 0.0.0.0 -o",
    "static-dev": "~/.node/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server ./dist/lead -p 4200 -a localhost -o",
    "format": "tslint --fix \"./src/app/**/*.ts\" && tslint --fix \"./server/**/*.ts\" && prettier --write \"./src/app/**/*.{ts,json,css,html}\" && prettier --write \"./server/**/*.ts\" && ng lint"
  },
```

The perfect solution would be to autostart the server and application with all provided startup options and also restart the application in case of a crash.

Would be very thankful for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 0):

[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) is a popular library for environment params management. You can start your app like this `NODE_ENV=prod node app.js` and can access this value from your app like this `process.env.NODE_ENV`.